# Why my application start takes too long when i'm connected with my work network?

Tags: oracle, macos, docker, networking, c3p0

I have an oracle database installed via docker and a local Java application that only connects to that oracle database. It takes 8 minutes when I start the application when my laptop connected to my work network (via their Wi-Fi or VPN) and 50 seconds when I start the application outside of my work network.
Java application uses c3p0 library.
Here is database configs

```
    <url path="jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:APP"/>
    <driver name="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
```

I am using mac os

Comment: MacOS dtruss will give you information about all syscalls your app is doing. sudo dtruss -p <PID-of-java-process> .

Comment: My internet connection is normally 200 Mbps, and when I connect to work VPN, it slows down to 10 to 20 Mbps, so if your app is bringing a lot of data from Oracle.... it might take 10 times longer on VPN.  I can tell how slow things are for me.